# Foreach for TCL List

Tags: tcl

I would like to ask a question regarding TCL.

Let say I have an instance `111` and under this 3 instances (`11100`, `11102`, `11103`) are attached. You may say `11100`, `11102`, `11103` are id's and then there are names attached to these ids such as A, B, C.

At the moment I got all these ids `11100`, `11102`, `11103` how can use these ids in loop to iterate in loop for three time so I can find each ids name.

Comment: Do you have some code snippet showing what you have done/tried already? That would be a good starting point to further help you. There's the foreach tcl wiki giving loads of examples: http://wiki.tcl.tk/1018 so you should get started easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you can iterate loop over the ids what you already have,

```
foreach i {11101 11102 11103} { 
    puts $i 
    ;# do what ever with i
}
```

Another option what you said is you have three variable A B C,

```
lappend list $A $B $C
foreach i $list { 
    puts $i 
    ;# do what ever with i
}
```

Comment: Yes these are three different ids attached to one id, so when I get these ids they are in list form i.e. Its list L and I want to loop through L one by one to seek what further is attached to the ids.

Comment: I am not correctly understanding what u r need is.. But if you think about nested list. go thru with this question it might help you. [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945880/append-elements-to-nested-list-in-tcl)