# Scala: Variable substitution

Tags: scala

Does Scala support variable substitution in the way that the subst built-in command does in TCL?

This has great use where you want to reference different variables or print custom strings inside a for loop, based on the index of the loop.

TCL example:

```
lappend [subst team_${team_idx}_list] $player
```

Comment: You'd use a nested data structure for this in Scala, not dynamic variable names.

Comment: [Ideally, you'd be using a nested list in TCL, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945880/append-elements-to-nested-list-in-tcl)

Comment: Macros could solve this.